# Ubuntu 12.04 Automounting ntfs partition

Tags: 12.04, mount, ntfs, fstab

Ive looked everywhere to fix this problem but I cant seem to figure out why its doing this. I have the following /etc/fstab entry to mount a ntfs partition using ntfs-3g.

```
UUID=01CD842715EC2180   /media/mediahd02        ntfs    defaults,user,noexec,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=007,fmask=117      0       2
```

The volume label for this partition is "MEDIA02"

So I have had no problems with the fstab mounting. The problem however is that it automounts again using MEDIA02 label. I'm not sure automounting is the right term for this as its just an empty directory. Deleting this directory and rebooting is causing it to appear again.

So listing /media I see both MEDIA02 & mediahd02

```
htpc@htpc:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sdf1 during installation
UUID=ec027544-b0e7-4145-99a4-905543a9781a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,noatime,discard 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdf5 during installation
UUID=1794409e-723f-41ac-9f31-ae059f377613 none            swap    sw              0       0
# Added all the lines below this
tmpfs       /tmp        tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777  0   0
UUID=0F70-3B06  /media/mediahd01    vfat    defaults,user,noexec,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=007,fmask=117  0       2
UUID=01CD842715EC2180   /media/mediahd02        ntfs    defaults,user,noexec,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=007,fmask=117      0       2

htpc@htpc:~$ cat /etc/mtab 
/dev/sdc1 / ext4 rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro,discard 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755 0 0
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
/dev/sdc1 /media/usbhd-sdc1 ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /media/mediahd02 fuseblk rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/sda5 /media/mediahd01 vfat rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=007,fmask=117 0 0
/dev/sdh1 /media/Windows_7 fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

Can someone shed some light as to why its doing this ?

Comment: What happens if you remove your fstab line? I would guess that the NTFS volume will get automounted as well, am I right?

Comment: please post your /etc/fstab and /etc/mtab

Comment: Ok ive listed those two files youve asked for.

Comment: Indeed If I remove the fstab line it gets mounted automatically

Comment: One small point: At the end of the both lines with `vfat` and `ntfs`, you have `0 2`. The fsck command is not reliable in Linux for those types of partitions, so you should change the final `2` to `0` instead (such as you already see for the lines with `proc` and `swap`).

Comment: good point. That should improve the performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok classic newbie error.

I created this script `/etc/udev/rules.d/11-media-by-label-auto-mount.rules` during setting up of my system which is what was causing this issue. Its suppose to be automounting usb disks for my htpc while ignoring system disks.

Contents of the script:

```
KERNEL!="sd[b-z][0-9]", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"

# Import FS infos
IMPORT{program}="/sbin/blkid -o udev -p %N"

# Get a label if present, otherwise specify one
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}!="", ENV{dir_name}="%E{ID_FS_LABEL}"
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="", ENV{dir_name}="usbhd-%k"

# Global mount options
ACTION=="add", ENV{mount_options}="relatime"
# Filesystem-specific mount options
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="vfat|ntfs", ENV{mount_options}="$env{mount_options},utf8,gid=100,umask=002"

# Mount the device
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/mount -o $env{mount_options} /dev/%k /media/%E{dir_name}"

# Clean up after removal
ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/umount -l /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /media/%E{dir_name}"

# Exit
LABEL="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
```

However my disk which I'm having problems with is `/dev/sdb1` and hence this script takes over. I have since modified it to ignore sdb by changing the line to `KERNEL!="sd[c-z][0-9]"`

Comment: Per new user Dave: Can we please see the correction? Also, identification of the offending line in the rules.d script would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry mate. Made the change so it should be obvious now.